# Meteor global 'this' seems to be undefined

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'm trying to factor out my increasingly big single CoffeeScript file in my Meteor project, and have followed the [official advice](http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript) on scoping global variables using `this`. However, even something simple like:

```
console.log("this=" + this)
@gave =
  Transactions: new Meteor.Collection("Transactions")
  Causes: new Meteor.Collection("Causes")
```

Generates terminal errors and the server won't start:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
this=undefined

/home/g/workspace/gave/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:321
}).run();
 ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'gave' of undefined
    at app/gave.coffee.js:6:11
```

According to the advice linked above,

> Global variables can be set in CoffeeScript by using this (or CoffeeScript's @ shorthand), because at the top level this refers to the global namespace (window on the client and global on the server).

So, I can't really figure out where I'm going wrong. Can you? :)

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working now. I randomly tried deleting the "use strict" line at the top of the file. Does anyone know why that would make a difference?

Comment: I submitted a fix.  It's been accepted and merged into the Meteor "devel" branch, and so will probably appear in the next release.  (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/933)

Comment: It *is*! :) I just read an email for 0.6.2, the last change listed was "* You can now set global variables in CoffeeScript files when using `use strict`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ES5 - 15.3.4.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4).

> NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this
>   value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null
>   thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to
>   all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

So, with the `"use strict"`, meteor's `.call(null)` will effectively give you a `this == null` =).

Comment: So Meteor is incompatible is just plain incompatible with use strict? Seems unfortunate.